# imposed new travel restrictions from several African countries

Tags: prepositions

Is "from" properly used in the following sentence from CNN?

> At least 70 countries, among them the United States, imposed new travel restrictions **from** several African countries after Omicron was first identified by South African scientists.

Comment: It sounds wrong to me. It could be either "...new travel restrictions on passengers from several African countries..." or "new restrictions on travellers from several African countries..." Or just "...new travel restrictions on several African countries..." [Travelers from the US have only one **l**.]

Comment: What do you mean by "Travelers from the US have only one l."?

Comment: In the UK it's "traveller": in the US "traveler".

Comment: No, it is not. The intended meaning is that the 70+ countries imposed restrictions on travelers from several African countries.

Answer (score 0):

In the original sentence, the meaning is that the "travel restrictions" are "from ... African countries" - which is far from the intended message.

It would be more clear and correct to specify "people", "passengers", "tourists" etc.

> At least 70 countries, among them the United States, imposed new travel restrictions **on people coming** from several African countries after Omicron was first identified by South African scientists.

Without "coming", it would sound like the people living in (e.g.) South Africa are also affected by the restrictions, even if they do not travel. "Originating" is another good alternative for "coming".

Comment: Is it okay to say "imposed new travel restrictions **on** several African countries"?

Comment: I guess it is at least strange. What does that even mean? That the countries cannot travel? Do you expect to see The country China going in vacation to New York? The restrictions apply to people - the people who travel, to be more precise.

Comment: Are you a native speaker of English, might I ask?

Comment: Of course you may ask. And no, I am not a native English speaker, but I use it almost daily for more than 20 years. However, you already have 2 people explaining you the same thing on this page - see comment from Old Brixtonian too ... :)

Comment: He says "imposed new travel restrictions **on** several African countries" is okay.

Comment: Grammatically it is OK, just like the original sentence. The problem is with the meaning.

Comment: Might I ask what your native language is? Metonymy may allow countries to refer to people.

Comment: Metonymy means that you name 2 different things with the same word - which means ambiguity. If you want to talk incsharades, go ahead. If you want to be properly understood, then learn to talk unambiguously. Metonymy is usually good for poems and for newspapers, because usually nobody's life depends on them anyway. And if you trust a newspaper with your life, then you have a much bigger problem that the English language.

Answer (score 0):

The usage "imposed new travel restrictions from several African countries" is idiomatic and perfectly intelligible. As a native reader, it is clear that this phrase means that many countries have decided to stop allowing people from specific African countries to travel and enter their own country. You don't need to explicitly state "people" or "people from..." since a travel restriction implicitly refers to people.

Comment: How about "imposed new travel restrictions **on** several African countries"?

Comment: It's more accurate to use **from** because they are not actually proactively restricting peoples' movements within the countries. They are just stopping people from those countries from crossing into their own country. 'restriction + on' usually implies a more direct measure that has an immediate impact on the target. 'restriction + from' is used to express that this is an indirect measure whereby they won't interfere with internal affairs of those countries, but they won't allow them to enter either.

Comment: restrictions on travel **to or from** x countries.